# Why has the word 'margarine' dropped out of fashion?

Tags: word-choice

Why do people go to awkward lengths to call butter substitutes by their brand names? (*would you like butter or Flora, luv, in yer baked potato?*)

I presume they are all technically margarine (which as far as I know was never a brand). So why do we not use the word *margarine*, as my parents did in 1948?

In the late 1940s it was probably a matter of some embarrassment to say you ate margarine, as it may have indicated you were poor or (in Britain) did not have enough ration coupons to buy butter.

But nowadays when people prefer it for health reasons, why is there not a satisfactory and generic name for it? I am constantly aware that people, in restaurants, shops etc are fishing around for what to call it.

Comment: Cognitive dissonance.  People couldn't stand the soft g before an a.

Comment: My first impression is that, with a vast array of margarine varieties to choose from, each with potentially huge variations from other brands, the specific naming has become a necessity. Butter has suffered comparably little change (compared to margarine); the single word suffices. Margarine, however, might be made of various oils and other extras that, if someone is to choose between two options, the brand of the margarine in question is the key to making a meaningful decision. One who prefers 'good' margarine over butter might choose butter over 'bad' margarine for the same reasons.

Comment: Basically, "margarine" sounds second-class, so everyone markets a branded "spread" of one sort or another.  It's just typical marketing.

Comment: My grandmother told me that when "oleo" first came out is was much oilier and greasier than today.  To her generation, "margarine" evokes "cheap, greasy, and fake".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21259/discussion-on-question-by-ws2-why-has-the-word-margarine-dropped-out-of-fashio).

Comment: @GregLee The name _margarine_ came from [margaric acid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecanoic_acid) (with a hard 'g') so it should really be pronounced with a hard 'g', it's just that no one does. The margarines I remember from the 1950s were pretty horrible, it's no wonder that the makers of modern spreads and cooking fats don't want to be associated with them!

Comment: The premise that margarine and current butter substitute spreads are the same thing with different names is mostly incorrect. The name has changed, in part, because the product is different, even though the products all have the same butter substitute purpose.

Comment: @ohwilleke Under the "Margarine Act, 1887" it is defined as follows: *The word “margarine” shall mean [2 any article of food, whether mixed with butter or not, which resembles butter and is not milk-blended butter] and no such substance shall be lawfully sold, except under the name of margarine, and under the conditions set forth in this Act.* Although this act has been significantly amended over the years, we can see that in origin and essence it meant anything that resembled butter that wasn't butter. And that is how I continue to use the term today.

Comment: @WS@ I'm sure that different countries have different legal definitions in statutes and regulations that have evolved since 1813 when it was invented and since 1887 as well. For example, the E.U. had to revisit all of its definitions of goods for customs duty purposes to standardize them when the customs union was established and there were probably new definitions during WWII as well. Still, one of the big differences was that oleo margarine used to come in sticks with the same firmness as sticks of butter, while new spreads usually with canola or olive oil are creamy.

Answer (score 6):

At least in the United States, margarine actually is considered to have a terrible health profile (full of carcinogenic trans fats), and no company that wanted to sell any of its spread at all would refer to it as margarine.

Comment: That may be true, but I see vegetable oil spreads being labeled as "margarine" every time I go shopping.  I won't eat the junk, unless actual butter isn't available.

Comment: It's worth noting that until a few years ago margarine was considered a healthy alternative to butter.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist In Britain you never see the word *margarine* on anything any more. And it is only people like me, whose first tastes were taken in the 1940s who still use the word generically to mean non-butter. The population at large is confused about what, generically, to call the various things on offer. We eat a thing called PURE, which comes in two varieties, Olive Oil and Soya. But since it is an emulsified fat I call it *margarine*.

Answer (score 6):

Part of the answer is in your question: Those of us who had older relatives who were scarred by the stigma of being too poor to afford butter, were taught that *margarine* was "low class".

The main reason was touched on by Hot Licks' comment: Advertisers have turned food into fashion. As it's not a "handbag", it's a "Coach" bag; those aren't "sneakers", they're "New Balance cross-training shoes", "margarine" is too generic a word for the myriad, proprietary concoctions (with fancy names) that protect people from admitting that someone in their family was poor at one time, and managed to develop (and pass on) a taste for the stuff.

Comment: I certainly don't know anyone in Britain who would be ashamed to admit to having eaten margarine. After all my generation can remember food rationing, when even the royal family were said to have restricted themselves to rations, eaten from the finest Chinaware. I do agree with what you say. But I think it is a pity and personally I insist on calling it 'margarine'. But then I often refer to 'trainers' as 'plimsolls' just to annoy people.

Comment: See now, that's where the Brits show class. In American culture it is rare for someone to miss an opportunity to point out what they got, that you ain't. (We are still known as crass and boorish in the rest of the world, aren't we?)

Comment: Well, some of you might be!

Comment: @WS2 +1 for plimsolls :)

Comment: This must be a uniquely American thing. I grew up poor, and never tasted butter until I entered the military in the early 70s. In Latin American we still call it _margarina_. And I use it every week when I am baking.

Comment: In our house there's just "butter" and "real butter"

Answer (score 3):

Margarine, by its official definition, has to contain at least 80% fat, according to [Flora](http://www.flora.com/article/detail/1104225/butter-vs-spreads):

> Margarine must have a fat content of 80% or more (similar to butter). So spreads are similar to margarines, but with less fat. This is why Flora is called a spread – it contains less fat than margarine.

So the simple answer is probably that most spreads nowadays are too “healthy” (or at least don’t contain enough fat) to fall under the definition of “margarine”.

I have a tub of “Tesco British Spreadable” that contains 11% fat and 15% saturates, falling woefully short of the standard for margarine.
Evidently companies are still struggling to come up with an actual noun to describe it, falling back on adjectives instead.

Comment: There's also an increase in blended spreads which contain different kinds of fats in varying proportions, e.g. butter with added oil to make it softer, margarine with butter or olive oil added for flavour, etc. It doesn't make sense to call them "margarine" or "butter". Hence the more generic "spread".

Answer (score 2):

I think that producers have been trying to find more appealing names that could be associated with a product ( margarine) that was no longer what it used to be, especially from the point of view of healthfulness:

> - In the mid-1960s, the introduction of two lower-fat blends of butter oil and vegetable oils in Scandinavia, called Lätt & Lagom and Bregott, clouded the issue of what should be called "margarine" and began the debate that led to the introduction of the term "spread".
> - In 1978, an 80% fat product called krona, made by churning a blend of dairy cream and vegetable oils, was introduced in Europe and, in 1982, a blend of cream and vegetable oils called clover was introduced in the UK by the Milk Marketing Board. The vegetable oil and cream spread I Can't Believe It's Not Butter! was introduced into the United States in 1981 and in the United Kingdom and Canada in 1991.
> - **In recent decades, margarine spreads have gone through many developments in efforts to improve their healthfulness**. Most brands have phased out the use of hydrogenated oils, and are now also trans fat free. Many brands have launched refrigerator-stable margarine spreads that contain only 1/3 of the fat and calorie content of traditional spreads. Other varieties of spreads include those with added Omega-3 fatty acids, those with low or no salt, those with added plant sterols, claimed to reduce blood cholesterol, and some made from olive oil or certified vegan oils. ( Wikipedia)

Comment: +1 for the research but this proves why we need a generic term for what you spread on bread. And since the technical name *margarine* still largely applies, why not that?

Comment: Well, as shown in the brief story I posted, margarine was not actually that healthy in its original version, so   marketing strategies decided to move forward creating distinct branded products not to be confufed with a general one like margarine used to be.

Comment: Yes, the name *margarine* has an OED example from as early as 1873: *U.S. Patent 146012 2/1   In all cases the oleo margarine is separated from the stearine. When it is cold..it constitutes..a greasy matter of very good taste, and which may replace the butter in the kitchen, where it is employed under the name of ‘margarine’. *The French word has one from 1821!*1821   A. Ure Dict. Chem. at Acid,   A substance of a peculiar kind, that M. Chevreul, the discoverer, calls margarine, or margaric acid.* Notwithstanding all that it was clearly WW2, and butter shortages, that launched it big.

Comment: M. Chevreul appears to have coined the word in 1812, from what I've found, albeit, only in French publications.  It is used in English from 1814.